# Web page Javascript and Extension (using js-ctypes) communication

Tags: firefox-addon, jsctypes

I have written a extension which makes use of js-ctypes. I have a function in the extension binded by js-ctypes with a C library function. Now, I want to pass some data loaded from the web page to this C library via Extension (js-ctypes). How do i do it ?

I came across - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages .
I understood the part where messages i.e strings are passed but now how do I use it pass data to my extensions' js-ctypes binded function from the web page ?

Precisely I am allocating a array in my web page js script. populate some data. Now I need to send this array/data to the C library function i.e invoke C lib function with this data

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with npapi

Answer (score 2):

Communicate with your extension, send data as JSON (sometimes arrays are wrong serialized).

For example you can send event:

```
var obj = JSON.stringify({arg1: 3, arg2: "some text"});
var event = new CustomEvent("YourAddonEvent", { detail: obj });
top.dispatchEvent(event);
```

In extension parse JSON and you will get object with arguments.

```
var args = JSON.parse(event.detail);
```

After load library and declare function, e.g:

```
var func = lib.declare("YourFuncName", ctypes.default_abi, ctypes.int, ctypes.int, ctypes.char.ptr, );
```

you can invoke your function:

```
var result = func(args.arg1, args.arg2);
```

Comment: But wouldn't that mean converting arrays to and from string  ? I must clarify that I need to deal with typed arrays here. That would be inefficient right ? am I missing anything ? If not, is there a better/alternative way to handle this ?

Comment: @lucent try this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Using_js-ctypes/Working_with_data#Example.3A.C2.A0Creating_an_array or if you have arguments in array you can use `call` or `apply` on function.